# How to identify the maximum value that is 2 times higher than next maximum value

Tags: r, dplyr

How to identify the maximum value by each row (ex: 20 of b1 and a4) that is 2 times higher than next maximum value (5 of b1 and a3) of the same row?

**sample input**

```
name    a1  a2  a3  a4
b1  1   1   5   20
b2  10  9   20  9
b3  1   1   1   1
```

**sample output**

```
b1  a4  20
b2  a3  20
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: What? This question makes no sense. Maximum value by what? Row? Column? Which is the "next maximum value? Are you treating the whole thing as matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -name) %>% 
  arrange(-v, name) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(logi = v / lead(v, default = min(v)) >= 2) %>% 
  filter(v == first(v) & logi) %>% 
  select(-logi)
```

the result is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
    name     k     v
  <fctr> <chr> <int>
1     b1    a4    20
2     b2    a3    20
```

Data used:

```
d <- structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("b1", "b2", "b3"), class = "factor"), 
                    a1 = c(1L, 10L, 1L),
                    a2 = c(1L, 9L, 1L),
                    a3 = c(5L, 20L, 1L),
                    a4 = c(20L, 9L, 1L)),
               .Names = c("name", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I am getting an error, when I run this on a tibble. It say 'name is not found'

Comment: To add more to the comment, my input for this code was coming after I transpose a tibble. It seems the values were transposed as 'char'. Still do not know how to avoid this problem. I am using this function to transpose c <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(b), t(b))). The first row and columns are characters and rest of them are 'int' but after tranpose it seems everything is 'char'.

Comment: @user1883491 Could you update your question so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I just solved it, thanks. I tranposed like this and it works great! `c<- b %>%
  gather(var, val, 2:ncol(b)) %>%
  spread(names, val)`

Comment: @user1883491 Why would you want to transpose the data.frame/tibble?

Comment: sorry it was my confusion. Your code works perfectly fine. @h3rm4n